# How can I disable the "Merge Button" on a merge request on Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-merge

I have a use case where I need to disable the Merge button for all merge requests if a pipeline is running on the target( usually master) branch.

Comment: I am wondering something similar but I'd like to be able to flip a switch to disable/enable merges. I haven't found anything that would allow this so far.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really any way to disable to the button itself, but you can ensure that `master` is a protected branch (which it should be by default) and then changing or ensuring that the [permissions to merge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#using-the-allowed-to-merge-and-allowed-to-push-settings) is limited to certain users or roles.

In the case where you want to prevent multiple merges to the same branch that may conflict, then consider [merge trains](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/merge_trains/) where a merge will take into account changes from any other merges to the same branch. This is a paid feature for any private projects, but is free for public projects on GitLab.com. On a self-managed instance though it's paid only.

Comment: Not what I am looking for but thanks for the info on merge trains. is it not available in the community edition?

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified. Edited my answer. On self-managed, unfortunately, you're right, it's not available without a paid plan.